# Retina Display and it's implementation confuses me

Tags: ios4, retina-display

Ok so I have been working with a designer who made the mockup of app in Photoshop. I am not using iPhone statusbar and using custom navigation bar which the designer made of 100px. In that navigation he put an icon of 48 pixels.

Now I have to transform into code and I am using UIWebView for the purpose. The layout he designed, I am going to make it in HTML/CSS that will be loaded in UIWebView.

Now the issue is, the PSD he made for the screen has SIZE of 640 x 960. In Iphone4 it's resolution rather than Physical Size. Base on setting of 640 x 960 pixel Image/PSD, he made the top bar of 100pixels. Now If I follow him that things getting messed up.

What I did that I just made everything half of size to accomodate 320 x 480 sceen size in CSS. I set Navigation Bar to 50px(for 320 x 480) and I put @2x.png image  (48 x 48) in it.

Now when I load app in my mobile it appears big as it should which gives me impression that 48 pixels did not appear as 24px Image with High Density.

I am quite confused, If I make 100px navigation bar then everything looks big as I am targetting big size while I have to target high resolution. How do I adjust elements(DIV) and Images in my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these articles on using CSS3 media queries and the viewport tag in order to help manage styles between normal and high definition displays:

[Targeting the iPhone 4 Retina Display with CSS3 media queries](http://blog.iwalt.com/2010/06/targeting-the-iphone-4-retina-display-with-css3-media-queries.html)

[iPhone 4 and iOS 4 Safari Detection and Behavior](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone4-ios4-detection-safari-viewport)

Comment: I am using media query. Somehow I am unable to get when normal imagebis used and when @2x file is replaces

Comment: Code is given here: **The titanum/html code** 
http://pastebin.ca/2176806
**CSS** http://pastebin.ca/217680